# relayjs fragment data's datatype

Tags: relayjs

I am planning to create a form that will automated render by passing in a relayjs fragment data.
However, I am finding difficulty to get the datatype of the fragmented data. Is there a way for me to get the datatype of the fragemented data.

Comment: Data type is set by the GraphQL type system. If you do not have access to the API you can access the schema using graphiql

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-tag). It is run before runtime, at compilation time. Taking in input a GraphQL fragment/query, it replaces it with an Abstract Syntax Tree representing that fragment/query, providing you useful information like the Type.